# A quick question about limit of $[u]$

Tags: limits

Suppose $u$ is a function. when $u\to \infty$ ,can we say : $\lim[u]=u=\infty$?

My justification is:

$$u-1<[u]\le u$$

Therefor if $u\to \infty$ then $u-1\to \infty$ too. and because of Sandwich Theorem we conclude $\lim[u]=\infty$ . Am I right?

Comment: Yes, you are right.

Comment: All is fine except $\lim[u]=u=\infty$ which takes way to much liberties with notations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you are absolutely right and since $u \to \infty$ in this case the left inequality suffices that is

$$[u]>u-1 \to \infty \implies [u] \to \infty$$

Answer (score 2):

Also note that

$$[x]=x-\{ x \}=\infty-t \;\;\;,\;\;\;\;t\in[0,1)$$

$$\to\infty$$

Where $\{x\}$ denotes the [fractional part of x](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fractional_part)

Comment: What is the $\{x\}$? I am not familiar with that.

Comment: @soheil check the edited answer